# Uploading bootloader to ATMEGA328 P

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, bootloader, arduino-duemilanove

I have a duemilanove which originally had a 168.  I have some ATMEGA328 P chips and I've put one into the duemilanove.  I am using a Uno as a programmer for the duemilanove.  I am running Arduino 1.8.2 on a PC which I understand doesn't need a capacitor installed on the Uno.  I've uploaded the sketch which makes the Uno an ISP, I have edited the avrdude.conf file, have wired up in accordance with http://www.crash-bang.com/resource/bootload-atmega328/ and the tutorial on this site.  When I run burn bootloader using the preferences set to verbose, the returned signature is correct for the P version of the chip I believe (0x95 0x14) and this is the value I have put into the avrdude.conf file.  However, avrdude is still insisting it is expecting to receive 0x95 0x0F and will not burn the bootloader.  I have no idea where it is getting this value from (I've even tried editing the iom328p.h file...). Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use a duemilanove?  Why not use UNO which has better spec and is actually still supported?

Comment: What board did you select, to "burn bootloader"? From what I know, putting an ATMega328 in a duemilanove board, will make it (more or less) identical to an UNO. So select the UNO from the boards, and press "burn bootloader", should work.

Comment: I've had the same issue with some standalone 328P project.
If you enable "Show verbose output during: upload" in the preferences menu, you can see the command which the Arduino IDE uses to flash your device - avrdude.
Copy it from the terminal window into a command prompt, and add "-F" to that to disable the device signature check.

Comment: @TobiasWeiß disabling the device check is not a good practice when you want to write to the chip and besides is not elegant. There must be a simple misconfiguration which has to be found and fixed

Answer (score -1):

The signature bytes are:

ATmega328 0x1E 0x95 0x14

ATmega328P 0x1E 0x95 0x0F

So it looks you have the wrong bytes for the 328P.